# Is there a standard or convention in doing configuration in .net core 2

Tags: .net-core

Is there a configuration provider already pre-configured in .net core that I can just use without having to add in boilerplate code?  In the same way that app.config files just work in full .net.

I'm writing a console app in .net core 2 and it needs some settings, a connection string and a few app settings that I would have previously just tossed into the app.config file.

I've started googling about configuration in .net core and found a whole heap of documentation about how flexible it is - you just add a file, make sure it gets copied to the correct location and then spin up a configuration builder add it the correct provider build it etc. etc.

As nice and flexible as it is I don't want to clutter up my tiny console apps with this config boilerplate - it feels like we have to roll our own config for each app.

Comment: package up the boilerplate code into a reusable extension method and use that

Comment: I've found that you can add the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager nuget package and app.config files are then magically supported without any boilerplate code. You can read settings using old-school ConfigurationManager class

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, in a .NET Core application, one would choose `JSON` setting files over `XML` configuration files, but it is still possible to use legacy XML configuration files if needed.

There is an API to access application setting files; just check out the following NuGet packages: `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml`, and this article might be a good reading: http://benfoster.io/blog/net-core-configuration-legacy-projects since it also covers the integration of `app.config` or `web.config` files, as well as how to create a custom configuration provider.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answers but I'm not sure you understood my question - I'm trying to enable configuration without having to write the boilerplate code which comes with those Extension nugets

Comment: @Twisted I have to say that your intention was indeed not that clear to me; I thought your question was about how to use `app.config` files instead of `appsettings.json`. Did not know that `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` has been readded to .NET Core 2.